# nginx rewrite url with dates in and change the format

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, ghost-blog

I'm just moving my blog over to Ghost and all was ok except for around 50% of my blog posts are broken due to the date not being zero padded i.e.

old site format: 
http://www.example.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/8/9/my-slug

new site format: 
http://www.example.com/2013/08/09/my-slug

Removing the /blog/index.cfm was easy via

```
location /blog/index.cfm {
    rewrite ^/blog/index.cfm(/.*)$ $1 last;
}
```

But cannot think of a way to zero pad dates (and there is around 700 posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put several rewrites.

```
location /blog/index.cfm {
    # 2013/1/1
    rewrite ^/blog/index.cfm(/\d+)/(\d)/(\d)(/.*)?$ $1/0$2/0$3$4 last;
    # 2013/1/11
    rewrite ^/blog/index.cfm(/\d+)/(\d)/(\d\d)(/.*)?$ $1/0$2/$3$4 last;
    # 2013/11/1
    rewrite ^/blog/index.cfm(/\d+)/(\d\d)/(\d)(/.*)?$ $1/$2/0$3$4 last;
    # all other
    rewrite ^/blog/index.cfm(/.*)$ $1 last;
}
```

Comment: I have slightlly difrent needs old site format: http://www.example.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/03/my-slug
new site format: http://www.example.com/my-slug
How to make redirect via 301? Can you help?

Comment: @shuron, it's really easy, but feel free to ask you own question

Comment: @AlexeyTen done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977170/nginx-redirect-url-to-new-format