# nginx redirect url to new pattern

Tags: nginx, configuration, ghost

I'm currently switching my blog from Wordpress to Ghost. There is nginx in front of ghost.
After migration i recognized that old urls

```
http://domain.org/2015/10/some-topic
```

are migrated like

```
http://domain.org/some-topic
```

So date is gone. Anyway there is some backlinking i don't want to loose, but i'm not so familiar with nginx...So what is the best way to redirect from old url style to new?

My curent configuration looks like:

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name domain.org;

            location / {
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
             proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://10.240.0.2:2368;
            proxy_redirect off;
            }
    }
```

What should be added?. I suppose i need new location but how it should look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a map:

```
map $uri $redirect_topic {
    "~^/\d{4}/\d{2}/(?<topic>.*)" $topic;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.org;

    if ($redirect_topic) {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/$redirect_topic;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://10.240.0.2:2368;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looks promissing. I've to test it. Is map functionality included in default nginx?

Comment: Greate works like a charm! <topic> notation was new to me as well ;)

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful. :) Maps are very useful and a good place to use regexes as [explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWRYbLKsS0I) by the author.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put into `server` section:

```
rewrite ^/[0-9]*/[0-9]*(/.*) $1 last;
```

But if you've any additional requests maybe would better in a `location` section (as you wrote).

About more information see on [the official nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

Comment: This solution rewrites internaly? I think maybe in long term it's better to send 301.

Comment: Maybe you've right. I didn't have many time to think about the question and it was my first idea.