# How to redirect http://example.com/2016/12/12/example-post/ to http://example.com/example-post/ in Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redirect

I have to redirect

```
http://example.com/2016/12/12/example-post/
```

to

```
http://example.com/example-post/
```

without breaking

```
http://example.com/images/2016/12/example.jpg
```

How to do that in Nginx? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `/%postname%` and replace it with current

Comment: I've already do that, but I need a 301 redirect  (claimed by Webmaster Tools)

Solved! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977170/nginx-redirect-url-to-new-pattern/32981299#32981299